# Flutter: How can I copy paste column values directly into my flutter UI from an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: flutter, dart, data-structures

Is there a specific widget for this? I want to be able to open a spreadsheet on my phone (a google sheet) or an excel file, select a column containing 10-50 latitude points, and another column containing longitude points. I want to be able to paste this directly into my app and create a latlng list from it.

I've tried using Sticky Headers (below) but it will only let me paste everything into one cell at a time:

```
StickyHeadersTable(
          columnsLength: titleColumn.length,
          rowsLength: titleRow.length,
          columnsTitleBuilder: (i) => Text(titleColumn[i]),
          rowsTitleBuilder: (i) => Text(titleRow[i]),
          contentCellBuilder: (i, j) =>
              Container(height: 50, width: 50, child: TextField()),
          legendCell: Text('Sticky Legend'),
        ),
```

Is there a way to modify this to accept entire columns from another spreadsheet via copy/paste?

Answer (score 4):

### Understanding how copy/paste works in Spreadsheets

Assume there is data something like this in Spreadsheet, or MS Excel

```
A1  B1  C1
A2  B2  C2
```

When you copy this data, it will be copied as a string in following format

`A1\tB1\tC1\nA2\tB2\tC2`

To put this data in your table
first split them into rows
and then into Cells

Example -

```dart
void main() {
  String data = "A1\tB1\tC1\nA2\tB2\tC2";
  List<String> rows = data.split('\n');
  List cells = <List<String>>[];
  for (String row in rows) {
    cells.addAll(row.split('\t'));
  }
  print(cells);
  //prints: [[A1, B1, C1], [A2, B2, C2]]
}
```

NOTE: If you copy only one column, each item will be separated with a `'\n'`(New Line).

### How to use solution with Flutter

Note that spreadsheets doesn't allow you to use new lines in a single cell. So when user copied a text into a cell or use `\n` then you can handle the data with a function and convert all data into a list as mentioned above.

Comment: You should parse the string with the [csv package](https://pub.dev/packages/csv) or something similar, since Excel cells can contain newlines.